# Table Cell font is weird and bigger than it should be (bold?)

Tags: html, css

The text font is really weird compared to the default one. It's bigger than the light font should be.

I already tried to change Font weight etc.

```html
<table>

  <tr>
    <th style="border-right: none; width: 130px;">
      <div></div>
    </th>
    <th style="width: 40%;">
      <div></div>
    </th>
    <th style="width: 25%;">
      <div>Threads</div>
    </th>
    <th style="border-right: none; width: 25%;">
      <div>Author</div>
    </th>
  </tr>

</table>
```

Current: http://prntscr.com/om9wwa
In the table cell: the font is bigger than the light one when you ignore that the one on the upper side is bigger.

- both fonts are "fontLight" (font face)

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

th tag has the default css `font-weight: bold;` To  make th normal, you should add css `font weight: normal;`

check out the code snippet

```css
th {
    font-weight: normal;
}
```

```html
<table>

    <tr>
        <th style="border-right: none; width: 130px;"><div></div></th>
        <th style="width: 40%;"><div></div></th>
        <th style="width: 25%;"><div>Threads</div></th>
        <th style="border-right: none; width: 25%;"><div>Author</div>          
        </th>
    </tr>

</table>
```

Comment: Omg I'm so dumb. Thank you a lot for giving me the tip. :)